# India Income Tax Deduction questions AY 2019-20

Tags: taxes, india, income

I am a Resident Indian Sr. Citizen,

I paid Mediclaim Insurance Premium of Rs.53808/- last FY (March 2019), by cheque, for my wife and myself (both senior Citizens)

I was hospitalised in December 2018  for 8 days and had to incur an expenditure of Rs.71000/-, paid to the Hospital through Credit Card,  over and above the amount paid to the Hospital directly by the Medical Insurance Company.

While filing the IT Return for AY 2019-20 (FY 2018-19), Can I claim deductions :

1. Under 80D (A) :  Medical Insurance Premium of Rs. 53808/- (Limited to Rs.50000/- for Sr. Citizen),

and

2. Under 80D (B) :  Medical Expenditure of Rs.71000/- (Limited to Rs, 50,000/- for Sr. Citizen),

totaling to Rs. 1,00,000/-.

Answer (score 1):

You can only claim one. If you are I, up to 50,000 on premium. If you are not insured, expenses up to 50,000

See the calculator at income tax website. https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/tools/deduction-under-section-80d.aspx